# Using request.security in a loop in Pinescript

Tags: pine-script

This is a piece of code which is calculating trend base upon highs and lows. I am trying to display trend of 4hr, 1d while being on 1 hr chart.
I am getting this error.

> Cannot call request.*() function inside if, switch or for

I am trying to display a box having 2 columns and 4 rows. One column with timeframe and second column showing trend. either uptrend, downtrend or sideways using pivot/swing highs and lows.

```
evaluateTrend(length, customTimeframe) =>
    var int numHighs = 0
    var int numLows = 0
    var string trend = "Sideways"

    var float high1 = na
    var float low1 = na
    var float high2 = na
    var float low2 = na

    // Find number of highs and lows
    for i = length to 1
        if high[i] > high[i+1] and high[i] > high[i-1]
            numHighs := numHighs + 1
            if numHighs == 1
                high1 := high[i]
            else if numHighs == 2
                high2 := high[i]
        if low[i] < low[i+1] and low[i] < low[i-1]
            numLows := numLows + 1
            if numLows == 1
                low1 := low[i]
            else if numLows == 2
                low2 := low[i]

    // Check if there are at least 3 highs and 3 lows
    if numHighs >= 3 and numLows >= 3
        var float high3 = na
        var float low3 = na
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error message is clear. You cannot call `security()` within a loop.

You can either create a function and then pass it to `security()` or get the values you need with `security()` and use them in your function.

The first way would look like:

```
get_sma(src, len) =>
    ta.sma(src, len)

daily_sma = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", get_sma(src, len))
```

The second way would look like:

```
daily_src = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", src)
daily_sma = ta.sma(daily_src, len)
```

Comment: Will it calculate all highs and lows? I need a function which can check pivot highs and lows of HTF in a given length(number of candle) compare them and tell the trend of price action. I want to have this info displayed on LTF. Can tou tell me how It can be done?

Answer (score 0):

**Let me explain what the error message means...**

`request.*()` has to be called within global scope.
Your error message suggest you tried this within a local scope instead.
You can't do that.
The request command must be executed every time the script is running!
And every time you need four white-spaces before the code you are creating a local scope.
Meaning you can't put the request command inside a `loop` nor `if` statement.
One and only exception is when creating a function, but as soon you put that function into a local scope it will result into the same error message.
You can read about scopes in [HERE](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/User-defined_functions.html?highlight=global%20scope#scopes-in-the-script).

I used a `tuple` for the return values, so the request command can have several commands within one call.
[HERE](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Variable_declarations.html?highlight=tuple#tuple-declarations) is a howto about `tuples`.

**Example...**

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)

[high_1D , low_1D]  = request.security(symbol = syminfo.tickerid, timeframe = "1D" , expression = [high, low])
[high_240, low_240] = request.security(symbol = syminfo.tickerid, timeframe = "240", expression = [high, low])
```

**This is the part where I did go over the top...**

You posted some code but there wasn't an example of the things you wanted,
so I made a whole script out of your wishes.

```
int length_240 = input.int(title = "Trend Length (4h)", defval = 2, minval = 1, display = display.none)
int length_1D  = input.int(title = "Trend Length (1D)", defval = 2, minval = 1, display = display.none)

evaluateTrend(float source_high = high, float source_low = low, int length = 2) =>
    counter_up   = int(0)
    counter_down = int(0)
    highest_high = float(source_high)
    lowest_low   = float(source_low)

    for i = 0 to length
        if source_high[i] > source_high[i + 1]
            counter_up += 1
            highest_high := source_high > highest_high ? source_high : highest_high
        else if source_low[i] > source_low[i + 1]
            counter_down += 1
            lowest_low := source_low < lowest_low ? source_low : lowest_low

    [counter_up, counter_down, highest_high, lowest_low]

[up_240, down_240, hh_240, ll_240] = evaluateTrend(high_240, low_240, length_240)
[up_1D, down_1D, hh_1D, ll_1D]     = evaluateTrend(high_1D, low_1D, length_1D)

string table_group = "--- Trend Table"
string table_xpos  = input.string("center", "X-Position", ["center", "left", "right"], display = display.none, group = table_group)
string table_ypos  = input.string("middle", "Y-Position", ["bottom", "middle", "top"], display = display.none, group = table_group)
string table_size  = input.string("auto"  , "Text Size" , ["auto", "tiny", "small", "normal", "large", "huge"], display = display.none, group = table_group)
var    table_trend = table.new(table_ypos + "_" + table_xpos, 2, 5)

if barstate.isfirst    
    table_trend.cell(column = 0, row = 0, text = "---", text_color = color.white, text_size = table_size, bgcolor = color.teal)
    table_trend.cell(column = 0, row = 1, text = "---", text_color = color.black, text_size = table_size, bgcolor = color.red)
    table_trend.cell(column = 0, row = 2, text = "---", text_color = color.white, text_size = table_size, bgcolor = color.teal)
    table_trend.cell(column = 0, row = 3, text = "---", text_color = color.black, text_size = table_size, bgcolor = color.red)

    table_trend.cell(column = 1, row = 0, text = "$ ---", text_color = color.white, text_size = table_size, bgcolor = color.teal)
    table_trend.cell(column = 1, row = 1, text = "$ ---", text_color = color.black, text_size = table_size, bgcolor = color.red)
    table_trend.cell(column = 1, row = 2, text = "$ ---", text_color = color.white, text_size = table_size, bgcolor = color.teal)
    table_trend.cell(column = 1, row = 3, text = "$ ---", text_color = color.black, text_size = table_size, bgcolor = color.red)

else if barstate.islast
    table_trend.cell_set_text(0, 0, str.format("4h: {0}", up_240))
    table_trend.cell_set_text(0, 1, str.format("4h: {0}", down_240 * -1))   
    table_trend.cell_set_text(0, 2, str.format("1D: {0}", up_1D))
    table_trend.cell_set_text(0, 3, str.format("1D: {0}", down_1D * -1))

    table_trend.cell_set_text(1, 0, str.format("${0, number, #.#############}", hh_240))
    table_trend.cell_set_text(1, 1, str.format("${0, number, #.#############}", ll_240))   
    table_trend.cell_set_text(1, 2, str.format("${0, number, #.#############}", hh_1D))
    table_trend.cell_set_text(1, 3, str.format("${0, number, #.#############}", ll_1D))
```

The important part I explained already at the top.

Then I modified your function to be able to give it values to calculate on.
I made this functions so it could also return tuple values.
Btw., don't be confused about the many parameters within the brackets (like `high` and `low`). It will work without those default values. But it makes the code more readable, and it is a backup this way. For example, you could call the function without parameters at all and get the result of your charts timeframe.

Inside the function I changed some things too.
You did all `if` statements two times, which isn't needed.
You also used many `var` declarations which isn't needed either in this case.
The best approach is to create all variables within global scope, use the parameters of the function to give it some things to work on, and use the output of the function to have new variables within global scope.

Last but not least, I created a table.
If you look closely it is the one and only variable within the whole script which needs to be declared as `var` to be consistent, and this is needed so it wont reinitialize one every tick.

You could park both `request.()` inside that function, but it is not needed. And you could park the table inside the function too, but this isn't recommended.

Comment: high_1D , low_1D]  = request.security(symbol = syminfo.tickerid, timeframe = "1D" , expression = [high, low])
Will it calculate all highs and lows? I need a function which can check pivot highs and lows of HTF in a given length(number of candle) compare them and tell the trend of price action. I want to have this info displayed on LTF. Can tou tell me how It can be done?

Comment: @TahaAhmad all output from `request.*()` are refreshed on every tick. The trick was to put those outputs into the function, and this gives you the result you want. an alternative approach would be using `request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1D", ta.pivothigh(5, 5))` but it will delay the output by the amount of `rightbars`

Comment: @TahaAhmad the function will return the last pivot only and count the related candles in that direction. there is no other way to do this, except when delaying the output like `ta.pivothigh()` is doing